# why my $('body').css('visibility', 'hidden'); is not working with Safari?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to print modal content and my code is working fine with `chrome` but it is not working with `safari`. I'm hiding body content using jQuery `$('body').css('visibility', 'hidden');` . I also tried using `opacity:0` and `opacity:1` instead of `visibility` but it didn't work. Below is the code I am using to print modal content

```
function printBtnOpen() {
    var modalId = $(event.target).closest('.modal').attr('id');
    $("#" + modalId).css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('.panel-collapse').collapse('show');
    $('.modal-body').css('max-height', 'none'); 
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        window.print();
        $('body').css('visibility', 'visible'); 
        $('.modal-body').css('max-height', '688px'); 
   },1000);
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the `@media print` media query that targets the print preview view?

Comment: Thank you! I didn't try it with `@media print` but I am also confused about how to implement it.

Comment: I've added some additional context in an answer below. Check it out and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you! I fixed it using `print.css`. I am using `@media print` to print the other page which has no modal. To avoid to create another file I was using jQuery to print modal content but didn't work for `safari` so now I created another file `print.css`.  if you can explain me why it wasn't working with `jQuery` and working fine with `css` it'll be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to accomplish this using the `@media print` CSS directive as oppose to JavaScript:

```
@media print {
    body {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .modal-body {
        max-height: none;
    }
}
```

You can add this to your existing external stylesheet or separate this out into a new stylesheet, for example one called `print.css`. If you take the route of separating the content into a separate stylesheet, you can add a link tag that looks like the following:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

The `media="print"` directive helps the browser to know which media the linked resource applies to.

**Reference:**

- [Mozilla Developer Network: Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)
- [Mozilla Developer Network: `<link />` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link)